# Odd Registration Form Behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

On my registration page I have the following defined in order for users to enter a display name value for their profile.  It's defined like this:

```
<input id="DisplayName" type="text" value="" name="DisplayName" data-val-required="Use must provide a display name" data-val-length-max="50" data-val-length="The field Display name must be a string with a maximum length of 50." data-val="true">
```

I can understand FF using my email address for the "Email" field but I've never used this value in the "DisplayName" field and the very reason I have a display name field is to make sure the users email address is never used as the display name.  Very confusing.

The property on the model is defined like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "...")]
[Display(Name = "Display name", Description="...")]
[StringLength(50)]
public string DisplayName { get; set; }
```

Why would FF insert the email in DisplayName field?

Comment: It's probably a heuristic that it picked up from other sites

Comment: I tend to agree with @SamIam; that doesn't sound like anything to do with your server-side code.  You might want to retag this for a browser or your JavaScript framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Firefox is making a 'best guess' on how to populate that field based on the input element and text around it, but it's getting it wrong. You can disable autocompletion by adding the property `autocomplete="off"`.

In Razor this will look like:

`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DisplayName, new { autocomplete = "off" })`